# How can I combine lists within a list into a single list?

Tags: python, list

When I pull data from my model, data comes in lists. I want to display this incoming data as a single list. I tried a few things for this, but it comes up in different indexes.

```
class Tickets():
    
    def __init__(self,username):
        self.username = username
        
    def getTicketList(self):
        ticketList = []
        userTicketModel = CekilisModel.objects.filter(username=self.username)
        userCount = userTicketModel.count()
        if(userCount > 0):
            while userCount > 0:
                userCount -= 1
                ticketList.append(userTicketModel[userCount].tickets) 
            ticketList.extend(ticketList)
            print(ticketList)
        return(userTicketModel)
```

Output:

```
["['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", 'Y666KCF', "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", 'Y666KCF']
```

What I Want Example Output:

```
['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']
```

Comment: So some lists in your output list are strings? Or they are list of strings and its just a typo

Comment: Yes, some of the data I pulled from this correct model come as strings.

Comment: You can run a for loop and then simply add each element to an empty list. Simple as list1 + list2 ?

Comment: But you gotta make sure the elements of your list are lists and not strings.

Comment: I tested this. The result I got was not a single list. You can test it too. The solution is not that simple.

Comment: What about JSON parsing?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to parse those string lists into actual lists is to use `eval()`, although I am not sure if its the best approach. Here is the code that does what you want using `eval()`:

```
from functools import reduce

# this assumes your individual strings are all of length 7 like in example
# `l` is the name of the list containing your `output`
l = [eval(x) if len(x) > 7 else [x] for x in l]
# then flatten the array using functools.reduce
l = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, l)
```

Also note, I am not sure what is the purpose of your code and where the `output` is coming from. If its from some invalidated user input, using `eval()` would be a huge security issue, as it essentially executes the code that is passed to it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

as @Arch113 said, eval is a good way:

```
o=["['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", 'Y666KCF', "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']", 'Y666KCF']
l = [eval(x) if len(x) > 7 else [x] for x in o]
print(sum(l, []))
#output
['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'Y666KCF', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'Y666KCF']
```

Answer (score 0):

The sound way would be to write a parser that would translate the individual data responses into actual lists. Since the strings look to be mostly Json-compatible, I'd run a Json parser over them. Just replace the `'` with `"`. E.g.:

```
import json

def _parse_tickets_response(tickets: str) -> List[str]:
    return json.loads(tickets.replace("'", '"'))

class Tickets():
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        
    def getTicketList(self):
        ticketList = []
        userTicketModel = CekilisModel.objects.filter(username=self.username)
        userCount = userTicketModel.count()
        if userCount > 0:
            while userCount > 0:
                userCount -= 1
                ticketList.extend(
                    _parse_tickets_response(
                        userTicketModel[userCount].tickets
                    )
                )
            print(ticketList)
        return(userTicketModel)
```

Btw, Python uses lower snake case.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't suggest eval.  Not even to say it's a risk.  Especially not when you have [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to use instead.

Just don't.

```
# this was formatted through `black`, mostly for the list comprehension bit
from ast import literal_eval

input_ = [
    "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']",
    "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']",
    "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']",
    "Y666KCF",
    "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']",
    "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']",
    "['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR']",
    "Y666KCF",
]


output_ = []
for v in input_:
    if v.startswith("[") and v.endswith("]"):
        v = literal_eval(v)
    else:
        v = [v]
    output_.extend(v)

print(output_)

# partially using a list comprehension, which can be faster
# the formatting isn't necessary, you could have it all on one line instead.
output_ = []
[
    output_.extend(v2)
    for v in input_
    if (v2 := literal_eval(v) if v.startswith("[") and v.endswith("]") else [v])
]

print(output_)

#cribbing the sum function from Talha's answer to make it more functional
output_ = sum(
    [
        literal_eval(v) if v.startswith("[") and v.endswith("]") else [v]
        for v in input_
    ],
    [],
)

print(output_)
```

#### output:

```
['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'Y666KCF', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'Y666KCF']
['J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'Y666KCF', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'J2V6UEQ', 'OOKXWXY', 'VXC7FGR', 'Y666KCF']
```